# Why does ['Mr David',23,'City'] become [[\'Mr David\',23,\'City\'] in Python?

Tags: python, text

My problem is this: **['Mr David',23,'City'] becomes [\'Mr David\',23,\'City\']**. Can you please suggest how to fix it?

here is some code if you wanna see..

```
path = r'D:/ListFile'
rdata = open(path,'rb')
ListNow = []
for ch in rdata:
    ListNow.append(ch)
print ListNow
```

*What I am trying to do:* I read it from a file and try to rewrite it to memory (because I dont know how to work with list stored in files which are on disk?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print a list in Python, it uses `repr` to reproduce the value, which will *represent* each list item as a Python string literal. If you want to print each value separately, you can do so:

```
for item in ListNow:
    print item
```

(arshajii’s comment below might explain that more clearly, by the way. Thanks!)

Comment: Just to clarify, when you print a list it *does* use `str` on the list itself, but `list`'s `__str__` uses the `repr` of all the elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a file `D:\listfile` with lines containing python lists such as

```
['Mr David',23,'City']
```

which you want to read into a list of lists. However as you loop over the file, each line is read to a string. So `ch` is a string, but you were expecting it to be a list.

If you trust the contents of the list file to contain safe expressions you can get python to evaluate the strings

```
ListNow.append(eval(ch))
```

This is dangerous if the listfile isn't trusted (for example if it contains data collected from a website) because malicious code in the listfile would be run. In that case you would have to analyse the string, starting with ch.split(',')